# Authorization error when trying to apply an index template to elasticsearch

Tags: kibana, aws-elasticsearch

so we have an elastic search service running in AWS, the elasticsearch version is 7.8.0. And I need to add an index template to limit the amount of shards that are allocated to new indices when they are added.

I followed this example of how to add an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/index-templates.html) and got this **very** simple template:

```
PUT _index_template/shard_limitation
{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    }
  }
}
```

When running this request from the inside Kibana's Dev Tools console I get the following error: `{"Message":"Your request: '/_index_template/shard_limitation' is not allowed."}`.    As well as an Unauthorized - 401 icon. I'm running this command with the **admin** user.

I tested it locally (elastic search running on my machine) and it all works fine. Any idea why this might happen?

SOLUTION:

As was suggested by @Ajinkya, the correct way to do this is to not include the "_index" before the template api. The correct way to achieve what I was trying to do is to type the following:

```
PUT _template/shard_limitation
{
  "index_patterns": ["some-pattern"],
  "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'_index_template' operation might not be supported in AWS elasticsearch. You can check supported operations for your AWS ES version [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_7_8)

You can still use '_template' API to add index template

```
PUT _template/shard_limitation
{
  "index_patterns": ["test*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! The settings weren't applied but the template went through.